# Link com Âncora

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Estou fazendo um site e tenho um link que, além de emitir uma mensagem quando é clicado, utiliza uma âncora para colocar a seção do site em destaque.

Estou fazendo isto da seguinte forma:

```
<a href="/alerta#destaque">Gerar Alerta</a>
```

Desta maneira, quando o usuário clica no link, é gerado um alerta e a página "desce" até uma div com o id "destaque" que mostra o conteúdo do alerta gerado.

O alerta é gerado a partir de uma função JQuery.

O meu problema é que este link só funciona uma vez. Na primeira vez que eu clico, tudo acontece direitinho. Só que se eu clicar uma outra vez no link não acontece nada.

Eu percebi que se o link da âncora fica visível na URL a ação do link não funciona.

Como eu poderia resolver este problema?

Comment: Cara edite sua pergunta como o seu código, vai facilitar para alguém te responder. Edite e coloque o HTML/CSS e JS, fale se usta usando plugins ou jquery etc.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode restaurar a URL da página (retirando o `alerta#destaque`) sem que a mesma seja recarregada usando o método `history.replaceState`.

Por exemplo: de `site.com.br/alerta#destaque` passa para `site.com.br`.

Na sua função jQuery citada na pergunta, coloque no final o código:

```
history.replaceState("", null, window.location.pathname);
```

O `window.location.pathname` retorna apenas o nome da página atual, ignorando parâmetros, hash etc. Ex.:

`site.com.br/alerta#destaque` retorna `/`

`site.com.br/index.php?alerta#destaque` retorna `index.php`

Comment: O problema continua a acontecer. A URL realmente volta ao estado original (aparece sem a âncora). Mas o segundo clique ainda não funciona, mesmo retirando a âncora da URL =/

Você sabe me dizer se é possível ir para uma âncora utilizando apenas JQuery e sem precisar de clicar em algum link? Por exemplo: toda vez que eu recarregar a página o JQuery me manda para aquela div específica?

Comment: sim isso dá para fazer, meta seu codigo na pergunta para podermos ajudar como deve ser. meta o html, css, js para podermos ajudar melhor